# Vim: Change syntax coloring rules when changing colorscheme

Tags: vim, color-scheme

In Vim, is it possible to change the syntax coloring rules for a given language, together when the colorscheme is changed?

**Here is an example:**

I installed some plugins for coloring matlab code in Vim. It provides several `.vim` files:

```
.vim/colors/matlabdark.vim
.vim/colors/matlablight.vim
.vim/ftplugin/matlab.vim
.vim/indent/matlab.vim
.vim/syntax/matlabcolours.vim
.vim/syntax/matlab.vim
```

It works very nice with provided colorschemes. However, I sometimes want to use different colorschemes, and when I apply another colorscheme (e.g. solarized), commas and semicolons have too intense background color. I checked into `.vim/syntax/matlab.vim`, and I see that commas and semicolons are assigned to the group `SpecialKey`.

I tried to edit that part of `.vim/syntax/matlab.vim` into:

```
syn match matlabComma        ","    display
syn match MatlabSemicolon    ";"    display
(...)
command -nargs=+ HiLink hi def link <args>     " creates HiLink command
(...)
if g:colors_name == 'solarized'                " added by me
  HiLink matlabComma         Normal            " added by me
  HiLink matlabSemicolonn    Normal            " added by me
else                                           " added by me
  HiLink matlabComma         SpecialKey
  HiLink matlabSemicolonn    SpecialKey
endif                                          " added by me
(...)
```

but nothing happens when I change the colorscheme to solarized. Then I tried to put this script into `.vim/after/syntax/` but also without luck.

I suppose that I need to somehow change the code of `solarized`, or any other colorscheme to achieve what I wanted, but I simply can't see how. I don't know enough about vim scripting to understand what files/scripts are executed when colorscheme is being changed. Probably only the `.vim/colors/<wanted_scheme>.vim` script.

If needed, the matlab can be found [here](http://www.mathworks.de/matlabcentral/fileexchange/28240-highlighting-matlab-files-in-vim).

Comment: What does `HiLink` do?

Comment: I think it is equivalent to `hi link`, or `highlight link`

Comment: I found where `HiLink` comes from. The code in the question is updated accordingly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the `:HiLink` command expands to `:hi def link`; the `def` means that the command just defines *defaults* in case there's no existing one. If the syntax plugin was already sourced once, that's not the case anymore, and your change becomes ineffective.

Now, if you don't mind manipulating the script, drop the `def`, and it should work.

Another way would be to redefine the link via an `:autocmd` that is triggered by the change in colorscheme:

```
:autocmd ColorScheme * if g:colors_name == 'solarized' | hi link matlabComma Normal | else | hi link matlabComma SpecialKey | endif
```

Finally, do you really need to switch colorschemes on the fly? Some plugins won't handle that gracefully, neither.

Comment: Just removing the `def` didn't seem to work, but adding `autocmd` to my `.vimrc` works nicely.

To answer your question, I sometimes change the colorschemes on the fly when I have different file types opened in the same vim, but the change of a colorscheme is not _that_ often. Still, I didn't know that changing a colorscheme could pose a problem. Can you maybe give me an example?

Comment: Some plugins define new highlight groups (with explicit colors, not just links) for them. A `:colorscheme` switch causes those to be cleared; they need to hook into the `:autocmd`, too, but some fail to do this.